# RuntimeError: Missing "jwks_uri" in metadata for flask and Azure AD authlib

Tags: authlib, flask-oauthlib, airflow-webserver

I tried login in via Azure AD in airflow container.
I setting de webserver_config.py

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    { 
        'name':'azure', 'token_key':'access_token', 'icon':'fa-windows',
        'remote_app': {
            "api_base_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID",
            "request_token_url": None,
            'request_token_params': {
                'scope': 'openid email profile'
            },
            "access_token_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            "access_token_params": {
                'scope': 'openid email profile'
            },
            "authorize_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
            "authorize_params": {
                'scope': 'openid email profile'
            },
            'client_id':'CLIENTE_ID',
            'client_secret':'CLIENTE_SECRET'
        }
    }
```

]

[image: Log Webserver UI]

See logging

```
Error authorizing OAuth access token: Missing "jwks_uri" in metadata
```

Comment: I found solution add  `jwks_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys`

Answer (score 4):

I found solution,
adding authlib 1.0.1 and add

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
{ 
    'name':'azure', 'token_key':'access_token', 'icon':'fa-windows',
    'remote_app': {
        "api_base_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID",
        "request_token_url": None,
        'request_token_params': {
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        },
        "access_token_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        "access_token_params": {
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        },
        "authorize_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        "authorize_params": {
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        },
        'client_id':'CLIENTE_ID',
        'client_secret':'CLIENTE_SECRET',
        'jwks_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: my case i did not need to install `authlib` because: my one shows 
```airflow@airflow-webserver-7cd49659dd-cd9x5:/opt/airflow$ pip freeze |grep auth
gcloud-aio-auth==4.0.1
google-auth==2.14.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.7.1
oauthlib==3.2.2
pydata-google-auth==1.4.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1 
```